# detecting key press python for loop doesn't work

Tags: python, keyboard

I have a for loop code in python that will detect a keypress

```
import keyboard
for x in range(100):
   if keyboard.is_pressed('f4):
      print('pressed')
```

but unfortunately, the code doesn't work with the for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a while loop because it is way more better for detecting the keypress and it loops the code forever until the condition is met.

```
while True:
   if keyboard.is_pressed('f4'):
      print('pressed')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "wait"

```
import keyboard
for x in range(100):
   keyboard.wait('f4')
   print('pressed')
```